# No viable alternative at input '>' in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cql3

What is the issue with these command cos for every command i am getting `no viable alternative at input '>'` error

```
CREATE TABLE collect_things (
           ...   k int PRIMARY KEY,
           ...   v <tuple<int,text,float>>
           ... );

CREATE TABLE collect_things (
           ...   k int PRIMARY KEY,
           ...   v tuple<float, float, text>
           ... );


CREATE TABLE tuple_test (
           ... the_key int PRIMARY KEY,
           ... the_tuple frozen<tuple<int, text, float>>)
           ... ;
```

Spec:
`[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.8 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]`

Comment: upgrading cassandra version solved it

Answer (score 4):

You could see more from http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html

To support future capabilities, a column definition of a user-defined or tuple type requires the frozen keyword. Cassandra serializes a frozen value having multiple components into a single value. For examples and usage information, see "Using a user-defined type", "Tuple type", and Collection type.

Note: Cassandra 2.1.0 to 2.1.2 requires using frozen for tuples:

```
frozen <tuple <int, tuple<text, double>>>
```

Cassandra 2.1.3+ does not require this keyword.